# Can SLButton or SLElement be used to dismiss a UIActionSheet presented in a popover?

Tags: ios, automation, subliminal

I tried:

```
SLButton *actionSheetButton = [SLButton elementWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Remove"]; // also tried same with SLElement

BOOL popoverDisplayed = SLWaitUntilTrue([UIAElement(actionSheetButton) isValidAndVisible], 3.0);

if (popoverDisplayed) {
    [UIAElement(actionSheetButton) tap];
}
```

I was able to dismiss/cancel the action sheet using SLPopover, but I'd like to test the button actions.

Thanks.

*Edit:*

The error logged in Instruments:

> Unexpected exception occurred `***SLUIAElementNotTappableException***`
>   for reason: Element '`<SLButton description:"Remove"`>' is not tappable.

Comment: The error is happening on the `tap` line, right?  So Subliminal is finding the `actionSheetButton` OK, but is failing to execute the tap?  What error(s) are logged in Instruments when you run this test?

Comment: Yes, the error is occurring on the tap line. I edited the question to include the error. I'm assuming Subliminal is finding it because it passes the isValidAndVisible check. Is that the way to check?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Subliminal is finding the button alright but it's not properly identifying it to UIAutomation to be tapped. I've filed an issue here (https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/issues/46) to track the two bugs in play; I have a fix pending for the first one and @AaronGolden and I are talking about how to fix the second one.

Comment: The fix is merged into master.  Andrew, can you give your test another try with the top of the master branch of Subliminal and see if it works now?

Comment: Thank you, it works. Compared to your test case in Subliminal, I present the action sheet using showFromRect:inView:animated:, which implicitly creates a popover to wrap the action sheet on the iPad. Just in case pointing it out, unless it looks identical to Subliminal, if it's worth having a separate test for that presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two bugs in Subliminal where Subliminal could not manipulate action sheets at all, and then further could not manipulate action sheets when they were in popovers. [This issue](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/issues/46) gives more details for anyone interested. The bugs are fixed as of commit [450f37ce28](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/commit/450f37ce2826d97c2073599537ef8dc5eca04aa7) on master. Thanks for the report @Andrew!